# Are there any known Wizards who prefer a muggle life?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

We know that some Wizards and Witches are familiar with the Muggle world, but are there some cases of people which start a life as a Muggle or "undercover wizard" in the Muggle community?

Comment: Does _undercover wizard_ mean they do or do not use magic?

Comment: use magic without the knowlege of the Muggles around him. He basically dont abandon all his magic to live as a Muggle.

Comment: Related: [Muggles and Magic Living in Harmony?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10061/muggles-and-magic-living-in-harmony)

Comment: @nestario If you're using magic then you're not living "as a Muggle", you're just the same as every other witch and wizard who lives in close proximity to Muggles (i.e. most of them).